# Is it possible to point domain to other domain

Tags: domain

How can I host multiple domains on my cloud service. Currently I have only one server, but when service becomes larger, IP might change. Is it possible to point domain to other domain, because if IP address changes, then customers must change IP address from their domain admin, which is of course unwanted work for paying customer.

Is there any way to point domain to other domain, which will then point to IP address that is in use.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a CNAME record in your DNS zone to point to another domain.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record

Comment: Not for the apex record (example.com), technically.

Comment: Yes, and that could be a problem. See http://superuser.com/questions/264913/cant-set-example-com-as-a-cname-record